# Can't disable Cloudflare's Rocket Loader for specific scripts. What am I doing wrong? Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cloudflare, rocket-loader

I'm trying to disable Cloudflare's Rocket Loader for specific scripts. At first I'm trying to disable it for mobile slider. I tried various combinations of this (and every other I found on StackOverflow) code:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'writeup-owl-carousel' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( "type='text/javascript' src", ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag     );
}, 10, 2 );
```

This script is responsible for the element that I'm trying to exclude from rocket loader:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'writeup_scripts' ) ) {

    function writeup_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'writeup-owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
    }  
}
```

When I paste this code in functions.php, the whole element (slider) dissapears and every javascript element on my website becomes unclickable. Does anyone know what's wrong with this code? I feel like I've tried everything...

Comment: As Owl Carousel depends on jQuery, you will need to add the `data-cfasync="false"` attribute to the jQuery library as well, otherwise Owl Carousel will get loaded before jQuery library